# Can the Protractor locators be used to test a directive in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

I have the following HTML that uses a directive to autocomplete 2 input fields, along with a drop down and a button.

What I'm wondering is what is the best way to test the from and to fields using Protractor Locators? Ideally we don't want to use css as it can be brittle. Does it need to get wrapped in something in the html to make it more test friendly?

```
<div>
  <form>
    <span>FROM</span><span>
    <div data-ba-auto-complete field="route.data.from"></div>
    <span>TO</span>
    <div data-ba-auto-complete field="route.data.to"></div>
    <span>Trip Type</span>
    <select data-ng-model="route.data.flightType" data-ng-options="flightType for flightType in route.data.flightTypeOptions"></select>
    <input type="button" value="Search" data-ng-click="route.submitData()";>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, *this is something you should not solve with `Protractor`*. Protractor is commonly used on a different, higher level where you mimic a real user in the real browser not going deep down into how the application under test was built and what components does it have.

Cover it with **unit and integration tests**, see more information and examples at:

- [Testing Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing#testing-directives)
- [Recipes with Angular.js: Testing Directives](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/directives/testing-directives.html)

Comment: I am trying to mimic a real user - this is the HTML i have to interact with for my browser test